# mod_rewrite condition - match "someword/" but not "someword/anotherword/"

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite a URL such as

> http://www.example.com/someword/

to

> http://www.example.com/someword/index/

But leave

> http://www.example.com/someword/anotherword/

untouched.

I'm fairly certain this shoudl be fairly easy to accomplish but I'm not so savy with Regular Expressions and the last couple of hours I've spent digging through googled regex guides has left me with no solution thus far.

> [-a-zA-Z0-9_]*/.+

suffices for giving me the opposite of what I want (matching "someword/anotherword/" but not just "someword/"). I need the opposite, to match just "someword/" but not "someword/anotherword/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
[-a-zA-Z0-9_]*/$
```

simple and fast tutorial:

```
.+ means any chracter one or more times
.* any character 0 or more times
$ is end of line
```

Comment: Thanks.  Interestingly, this works properly regexpal but when I add it to my .htaccess it doesn't recognize either variety of the URL.  I know my RewriteCond and RewriteRule is correct because if I change the condition to simply .* it works for any URL (as one would expect).  I know different engines do regex slightly differently which may account for why your expression works in regexpal but not in my RewriteCond.  I'm using ISAPI_Rewrite.

Comment: Could you paste your RewriteCond and RewriteRule?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^[-a-zA-Z0-9_]*/$ [NC]`
`RewriteRule (.*) /$1index/ [L,R=301]`

Comment: try this: `^/[-a-zA-Z0-9_]*/$`